# Unity - lighting tunnel scene

Tags: unity-game-engine, lighting

I am making metro simulator with cabin view. I move with camera along spline and I use spot light with the same position/rotation as main camera. The spotlight cone is pointing in tangent direction (first derivative of spline).

But some parts of tunnel are not lighted (very dark). I can't figure out where the problem is. 
Light is placed inside of tunnel, walls of tunnel has correct normals (pointing inside), orientation of light is correct. I tried to add other child-lights with some offset or rotation. I tried to change various light settings (intensity, spot angle etc.) but nothing helps. Dark parts still remain dark. Any idea or suggestion? Thanks, Pavel.

[tunnel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNMdD.png)

[without_normal_map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3g4Y.png)

Comment: Are you procedurally generating the tunnel mesh? If so, can I see the code?

Comment: No, I am loading tunnel segments from Resources and deforming their mesh along curve using methods like spline.GetPoint() or spline.GetDirection(). 
After it I don't forget to call mesh.RecalculateBounds ().
Now I changed in "lighting" window "Ambient GI" from baked to realtime. But I want to have 0 ambient light. It seems like the realtime lighting from the spot doesn't work correctly.

Comment: For the ambient lighting thing, change Ambient Source to Color and Ambient Intensity to 0 in the Environment Lighting section in the Scene tab of the Lighting window. Are you calling mesh.RecalculateNormals() at any point?

Comment: Thank you, you saved me. Calling mesh.RecalculateNormals() helps. Now all parts of tunnel are lighted.
But I don't understand it because I had normals correctly oriented in blender modeller and with more complex modells there was no such problem.